# Raspbian Stretch C920 webcam driver LED control regression?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, driver, webcam, v4l2

In a previous Stack Overflow post (April 16th 2018), [Raspberry Pi : use VLC to stream webcam : Logitech C920 [H264 Video without transcoding + Audio + LED control]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846400/raspberry-pi-use-vlc-to-stream-webcam-logitech-c920-h264-video-without-tran), I described how to use the Pi + Logitech C920 as a webcam stream device with audio+video+ LED control.

At that time, I had access to microphone record + Logitech C920 LED controls. And it worked pretty well!

Quote :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl --all
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : uvcvideo
    Card type     : HD Pro Webcam C920
    Bus info      : usb-3f980000.usb-1.5
    Driver version: 4.14.30
    Capabilities  : 0x84200001
[...]
zoom_absolute (int)    : min=100 max=500 step=1 default=57343 value=100
led1_mode (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
led1_frequency (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=0 value=0
(print stopped here)
```

A few days ago, I performed a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and I am now with driver 4.14.50 and I no longer have access to LED control:

```
[2018-07-07 14:18:44 sam.] pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo v4l2-ctl --all --list-devices -L -D
HD Pro Webcam C920 (usb-3f980000.usb-1.2):
        /dev/video0

Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : uvcvideo
        Card type     : HD Pro Webcam C920
        Bus info      : usb-3f980000.usb-1.2
        Driver version: 4.14.50
        Capabilities  : 0x84200001
[...]
zoom_absolute (int)    : min=100 max=500 step=1 default=57343 value=100
(print stops here)
```

Using another tool, same results:

```
[2018-07-07 14:23:18 sam.] pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo uvcdynctrl -i /usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml
Importing dynamic controls from file /usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml.
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'Pan (relative)' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'Tilt (relative)' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'Pan Reset' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'Tilt Reset' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'LED1 Mode' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'LED1 Frequency' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'Disable video processing' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'Raw bits per pixel' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml: error: video0: unable to map 'Raw bits per pixel' control. ioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) failed with return value -1 (error 2: No such file or directory)
```

So, the LED mode and LED frequency are no more available (no more `led1_mod (menu)` available.

Furthermore, I can't obtain audio stream from built-in microphone anymore.

1. How can I revert to previous driver version?
2. How can I find a changelog of the drivers?
3. Should I open a ticket at raspbian github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get LED control back.

I suspect some USB interfaces interferences.
I have a Rii wireless keyboard attached to my Pi.
I did the following:

1. execute: `uvcdynctrl -c`. LED control is not in command output
2. Unplug the Rii USB dongle
3. execute: `uvcdynctrl -c`. LED control is not in command output
4. Replug the Rii USB dongle
5. execute: `uvcdynctrl -c`. LED control appears magically

Final output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uvcdynctrl -c
Listing available controls for device video0:
Brightness
[...]
LED1 Mode
LED1 Frequency
```

This survived to a reboot.

useful sources: http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/

---

EDIT: the following is NOT necessarily relevant

I first I wandered over the interwebs and found [this page](http://www.linuxpedia.fr/doku.php/materiel/webcam/uvcvideo) concerning the driver `uvcvideo`

command to execute :

```
sudo update-usbids
```

Man page extract:

> Linux USB Utilities
>
> update-usbids - download new version of the USB ID list DESCRIPTION
>
> update-usbids fetches the current version of the usb.ids file from the primary distribution site and installs it.
>   This utility requires either wget or lynx to be installed. If gzip or bzip2 are available, it automatically downloads the compressed
>   version of the list.

Rexecuting the command `sudo v4l2-ctl --all --list-devices -L -D` gets the led control back.
However, it did not resist to a `sudo reboot`, so something was missing.

EDIT 2018-12-02: With my raspi, a `sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` seemed to fix the problem. I can't say for sure what happened that allowed the control to come back for good.

Comment: I don’t plan to put an official “accepted answer” yet: I have no clue whatsoever to whatever happened and why it is working again after unplug/replug another Possible interfering USB device.

Comment: Several years later, I've just encountered the same issue on Debian Bullseye. The working system with LED control access had `libwebcam0` installed, the non-working system didn't - and confusingly the package both didn't exist (`apt` threw an error) and no related files existed (`apt-file` came up empty). Very confusingly, `/etc/apt/sources.list` was identical on both systems. Eventually discovered that `libwebcam0` is in `bullseye-backports` (which wasn't configured on the working system??), but once I had that repo added `libwebcam0` showed up and LED control immediately worked.